# how to run an action on a kubernetes node (not inside container) whenever a pod is scheduled or unscheduled on it?

Tags: kubernetes

I need to run a script on a *node* shell level (**not inside the container**) whenever a pod is scheduled or unscheduled on it. I've searched documentation, but found only ways to add hooks running inside containers (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/, https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#container-probes). Does kubernetes have an API I could use to achieve this somehow?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is what you should do

1. use event exporter to capture those events
2. Deploy a webhook service
3. invoke the webhook when shedule or unshedule event happens
4. via webhook you should be able to trigger a script